# Upgrading mongo-java-driver to Version 3.9.1

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

I am in the midst of upgrading the Spring version of one of our projects. As a result of this, the MongoDB library also had to be upgraded.

I am not able to track what the previous version of the MongoDB library used was, but the current version is now 3.9.1.

I have the following piece of code that doesn't work because of the upgrade, how should I rewrite it?

```java
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientURI;
import com.mongodb.ServerAddress;

public sampleMethod() {
  MongoClient client = null;

  if (...) {
      List<ServerAddress> saList = new ArrayList<>();
      for (...) {
          saList.add(...);
      }
      client = new MongoClient(saList);
  } else if (...) {
      MongoClientURI mongoClientURI = new MongoClientURI("mongodb://...");
      client = new MongoClient(mongoClientURI);
  } else {
      MongoClientURI mongoClientURI = new MongoClientURI("mongodb://..." + this.encryptedProperties.getProperty("mongo.username") + "....");
      client = new MongoClient(mongoClientURI);
  }

  return new MongoTemplate(client, srcDbname);
}
```

The problem now is with the return statement, because post Version 2.1, `MongoTemplate`'s signature is now `public MongoTemplate(com.mongodb.client.MongoClient mongoClient, String databaseName)`. Pre Version 2.1, it was `public MongoTemplate(com.mongodb.MongoClient mongoClient, String databaseName)`.

I was looking at the [documentation](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.9.1/com/mongodb/client/MongoClient.html) for the `MongoClient` interface (`com.mongodb.client.MongoClient` package) & it states that "Instances of this class can be created via the `MongoClients` factory.". Looking at [`MongoClients`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.9.1/com/mongodb/client/MongoClients.html), the methods can't accommodate the creation of `MongoClient` with parameters `List<ServerAddress>`, `MongoClientURI` like [`MongoClient`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.9.1/com/mongodb/MongoClient.html) (`com.mongodb.MongoClient` package) does.

| Package | Old Version | Link | New Version | Link |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| mongo-java-driver / com.mongodb | not sure, couldn't locate but will update | - | 3.9.1 | https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.9.1/index.html |
| org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb | 2.0.8.RELEASE | https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/2.0.8.RELEASE/api/ | 3.2.0 | https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/3.2.0/api/ |

Please bear with me as I am a junior dev (6 months of work experience) & I'm not familiar with upgrading project versions, thank you for your understanding

I am not sure how to proceed, I am currently reading the docs & doing some Google searches to see what a possible solution would be

I don't have experience in MongoDB

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're upgrading to version 3.2 of Spring Data MongoDB. As per [the reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/3.2.0/reference/html/#upgrading.2-3), that major version series (3.x) requires you to use the 4.x version of the MongoDB Java Driver.

> 7.1. Dependency Changes Instead of the single artifact uber-jar mongo-java-driver, imports are now split to include separate
> artifacts:
>
> org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-core (required)
>
> org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-sync (optional)
>
> org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-reactivestreams (optional)
>
> Depending on the application one of the mongodb-driver-sync,
> mongodb-driver-reactivestreams artifacts is is required next to the
> mandatory mongodb-driver-core. It is possible to combine the sync and
> reactive drivers in one application if needed.